# Using TFS to generate version header file

Tags: c++, tfs

We are thinking about adding automatic versioning to a native c++ project being developed and automatically built by Team Foundation Server. Ideally, we would have the build start (which checks out all the newest versions from TFS), then as a first step, get the build number from TFS, create a header file, then check that file back IN before continuing the build. Is this even possible to do a checkout / check-in during a build like that?

I'm not too familiar with how TFS works and the capabilities of retrieving information from it, and neither is anyone else on our team, this is the first time we are using it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could. Here is a great web site showing how to do it for the AssemblyInfo's for C#, so you'd have to adjust the solution a bit but it should show you enough o complete your task.

Be very careful with Check Out/In in high volume build environment. You will tend to get a lot of "couldn't check out file already locked", and conflicts on check in because another build checked in after this build check out. Use custom tasks with a lot of error handling and verification and the ability to handle conflicts. Do Not Use TF.EXE in a high volume.

[Web Site](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, I don't know if it's possible to do this wil the built in build activities (probably not), however, you can use Invoke Process to call out to pretty much anything else you want, so you could try calling tf.exe (i.e. set the FileName to *path*\tf.exe and the Arguments to "checkout *fullpathtothefile*") to check out a file, do your edit/change (probably in another Invoke Process activity), then use Invoke Process to check it back in.

Just throwing the idea out there!

Answer (score 0):

Don't checkin the version file - it will cause trouble to no end. Instead, generate it on-the-fly using the build name which TFS provides, and compile with it. We started with [Wintelect's solution](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/09/05/tfs-2010-build-numbers-file-versions-from-inside-your-c-and-c-projects.aspx) (which supports C++, C# and other languages), and modified it to include the build's actual version string as a string.

Warning: Creating the file each time will break incremental build. We ended up re-creating the file only if it doesn't exist, which means that increment builds have incorrect build numbers - but our "official" builds are not incremental, and have the correct number.

Comment: Ok, I am working on it now and at least have some ideas. My manager keeps insisting on the header that is generated being checked in so that we can look back and track the version. I too think it will cause some issues though.

Comment: The correct way to track versions is through label. Any non-gated build (manual, CI, rolling, scheduled) will create a label, and you can see which version contains what this way.